# Getting URL of a picture on imgur

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, imgur

I am trying to automate a process of downloading imgur files, and for this purpose I am using beautifulsoup to get the link however to be honest I am pretty lost on why this doesn't work, as according to my research it should:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup("http://imgur.com/ha0WYYQ")
    imageUrl = soup.select('.image a')[0]['href']
```

The code above just returns an empty list, and therefore an error. I tried to modify it, but to no avail. Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: It is `src` and the image does not seem to contain an `a`...

Comment: I'll usually just tack a `.jpg` to the end of any imgur url and I get redirected directly to  the image... `.png` works too...

Comment: Okay, so if I want to find it via src what do I do then? Because that is also what I tried but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="post-image">


                        <a href="//i.imgur.com/ha0WYYQ.jpg" class="zoom">
                                    <img src="//i.imgur.com/ha0WYYQ.jpg" alt="Frank in his bb8 costume" itemprop="contentURL">

            </a>


</div>
```

this is the image tag, the `"post-image"` is a single word, can not be separated.

```
imageUrl = soup.select('.post-image a')[0]['href']
```

shortcut for select one tag:

```
imageUrl = soup.select_one('.post-image a')['href']
```

To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You can pass in a **string** or an **open filehandle**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong with your approach:

- `BeautifulSoup` does **not** expect an url, so you will need to use a library to fetch the HTML stream first; and
- Your selector seems invalid based on what I can see it should be `.post-image a`.

```
r = urllib.urlopen('http://imgur.com/ha0WYYQ').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
soup.select('.post-image a')[0]['href']
```

Or more elegant:

```
with urllib.urlopen('http://imgur.com/ha0WYYQ') as f:
    r = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
    result = soup.select('.post-image a')[0]['href']
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch, I am currently encountering some problems with gifv files but not with gif files. For example this one: i.imgur.com/hKONDKp.gifv it does not seem to download the entire file, got any idea why?

Comment: How do you mean it does not *download*. The soup will not download the file it will only *extract* the url.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I am confusing this an another question I had. Sorry

Comment: @nonein: In that case I propose you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to keep separate questions separate.